# Curl / php Empty response from PayPal IPN url

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-ipn

In the past couple of days, our PayPal IPN has stopped working and receiving a empty response from PayPal.  Nothing has changed on the server or in our code.

Attempting to cUrl to the PayPal IPN url simply returns an empty response.

```
$url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print $data;
```

The above should return "INVALID" and works as expected on my localhost and from other servers.
Changing the url to any other domain other then PayPal also works without issues.

So it seems it only received the empty response from paypal.com

I wonder if any one has run into the issue or could give pointers where to look in the hope to- resolve it?

Kind Regards
Musaffar

Comment: For me it returns Invalid. Maybe check with the PHP version ?

Comment: Sorry i have tested it and it works well. Even if i use `file_get_contents('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate');` i receive `INVALID`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Paypal made some security changes at the weekend. Some oscommerce users have been getting similar symptoms since Sunday with the curl error turning out to be:

> SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

In their cases it was due to the local certificate copy only having the Paypal certificate and not the root or intermediate certificates, with the solution to update it.

The working certificate can be found in:
[OSCOM Phoenix github](https://github.com/gburton/CE-Phoenix/blob/master/ext/modules/payment/paypal/paypal.com.crt)

Comment: Not only do they not inform us, they don't even document what they did and support seem to have no idea at all. Keeps us in work, though!

Comment: When clients request Paypal I simply refuse now, I recommend Stripe or one of a number of other logical and user friendly implementations. I simply don't need the stress of Paypal changing their systems without informing developers or clients.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your grievances, did make me feel better knowing I wasn't the only one feeling I was left around shooting in the dark.

The issue resolved itself on Monday night, therefore I'm hoping this will be enough for now.

Answer (score 1):

I would perhaps start checking if `curl` gave you any errors. PHP gives you in this case `curl_errno($ch)` and `curl_error($ch)` which will return a message or respectively the error code to it.

In case there is nothing suspicious to it. I would perhaps try to validate if you're able to run the above from your CLI on the server. (requires SSH access to it)

```
curl -H "User-Agent: ..." "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate"
```

I hope this gives you a good starting point. Please let me know if this helps or if you need more ideas.

**Edit#2: After comments where added from the author:**

> cUrl does indeed return an error : error 35 and the error message is as follows:

```
error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

In this case I would guess that your system is outdated and does not support the SSL ciphers from paypal. You could try to force a specific TLS version. As of today paypal webservers support only TLS1.2 or TLS1.3. This is how you can force it:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
```

or

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_3);
```

Additionaly @Preston PHX mentioned in a comment a good refernces for this issue coming from paypal:

- https://github.com/paypal/TLS-update#php
- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/info-security-guidelines/

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestions.  cUrl does indeed return an error : error 35 and the error message is as follows:

```
error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

Comment: I should also add that the server has curl 7.22.0 and OpenSSL 1.0.1 installed

Comment: @MusaffarPatel thanks for sharing more insight! Could you share the OpenSSL version which was compiled into PHP? `php -i | grep OpenSSL`. Another option could be to force the TLS instead of SSL by setting: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1);`. My assumption is that your compiled php version of curl tries to chose SSL over TLS.

Comment: @MusaffarPatel as addition to that: Paypal's webserver does not support SSL ciphers anymore and reduces their capability to TLS1.2 and TLS1.3.

Comment: Hi Cristoph, Open SSL version 1.0.1 in installed and I tried forcing TLS via curl_setopt but that didn't make a difference unfortunately.

Comment: Which version of OpenSSL 1.0.1? You need `1.0.1c` or later, here are some particular guidelines for PHP https://github.com/paypal/TLS-update#php

Separately, you also need to ensure you are able to validate PayPal's SSL certificates. See https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/info-security-guidelines

Beyond that, it's basically an issue for you or a competent sysadmin to resolve. Do some research and troubleshooting

Comment: @MusaffarPatel I find the suggestion and the links of Preston very useful for your specific case. I have adopted my answer to include a summary of the comments. Preston I hope this is ok for you that I re-used your suggestions.